# Reversing a string enter by user in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write code in java to reverse string enter by user the program runs fine without any errors but as I press enter after entering the string it show the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at javaprograms.JavaPrograms.main(JavaPrograms.java:16)
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)"

Here is My code:

```
   package javaprograms;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class JavaPrograms {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
   String str;
   int length;
   System.out.println("Enter String: ");
   str=s.nextLine();
   length=str.length();
   char[] arr;
   arr=str.toCharArray();
   for(int i=length ; i>0 ; i--)
  {
          System.out.print(arr[i]);
  }
    }
    }
```

Comment: array index starts at 0 and goes to size - 1, you need to iterate from `length - 1` to `0`, so change to `for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )`

Comment: if your string has a size of 12 then the max index for that string is going to be 11 (length - 1) because the first index is 0. 0 to 11 is 12 characters total.

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());`

Comment: Hint: you expect others to spend their time to help you with your problem. So you please spend the few seconds it takes to properly format / indent your question. Indentation matters a big deal, and that *preview* window exists for a reason. So that you are able to assess the quality of your input before hitting the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
for(int i=length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes are zero-based. This means they go from 0 to the array's length - 1. Your `for` loop is off by one:

```
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of reversing string.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-in-java-5-different-ways/

easiest would be:

```
    char[] try1 = input.toCharArray(); 
    for (int i = try1.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        System.out.print(try1[i]);
```

https://ideone.com/e.js/n7j83x

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class JavaPrograms {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  String str;
  int length;
  System.out.println("Enter String: ");
  str = s.nextLine();
  length = str.length();
  char[] arr;
  arr = str.toCharArray();
  for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   System.out.print(arr[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be

```
string reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
System.out.print(reversed);
```